# Resolution scaling for lower resolution image

Tags: resolution, images

I have a question about the hardware logic behind rendering a lower quality image or game (i.e. 1080p) on a higher resolution monitor (i.e. 1440p).

In given examples for the first row, 1920 pixels need to be scaled into 2560 pixels and in a smaller chunk (9 pixels into 12 pixels).

imagine the lower image to be a repetition of 3 pixels of red and 3 pixels of blue.

[image: 9 pixels]

How is this set of 9 pixels scaled into 12 pixels??

[image: 12 pixels]

How are these white pixels colors determined? Is it a middle ground color based on percentage of nearby colors?

If that's the case, is it fair to say running a game on 1080p setting on a 1080p monitor is actually better than running the game with same settings of a 1440p monitor?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to your question.  The answer is going to be a function of the game's software/engine and it's art assets - if any, the GPU's driver and software settings, and the monitor itself.  Each on of those can modify the output of what you see.

In general, if something is truly being upscaled (as in adding data where there wasnt any), one or more of the aforementioned will try to determine makes the most sense.  It could be averaging the colors around the pixel, blending the colors, or any number of different algorithms.